# How can I only show the profile picture of a user (and not his name) in a sharepoint column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

How can I only show the profile picture of a user (and not his name) in a SharePoint column?

I have set the column Person to only picture. but still get the name with it.

I have found a JSON code which displays the picture but it is with the name also:

```
{
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "flex-direction": "column",
  "align-items": "flex-start",
  "margin-top": "6px",
  "padding-right": "8px",
  "width": "100%",
  "overflow": "hidden"
    },
 "children": [{
  "forEach": "personIterator in @currentField",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
   "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
  },
  "style": {
   "display": "inline-flex",
   "align-items": "center",
            "height": "28px",
            "overflow": "hidden",
   "border-radius": "12px",
   "padding-right": "8px",
   "margin": "2px"
  },
  "children": [
            {
    "elmType": "img",
    "attributes": {
     "src": "=@currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$personIterator.email]",
     "title": "[$personIterator.title]"
    },
    "style": {
     "width": "28px",
     "height": "28px",
     "display": "block",
     "border-radius": "50%"
    }
   },
   {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "[$personIterator.title]",
                "attributes": {
                    "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
                    "class": "nameplate-title"
                },
                "style": {
                    "padding-left": "5px",
                    "white-space": "nowrap",
                    "font-size": "12px"
                }
            }
  ],
  "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]"
 }]
}
```

How can I only display the picture?

Comment: Is this a single selection person column or multiple selection person column?

Comment: Multiple selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this JSON for your person column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "personIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
      },
      "style": {
        "height": "28px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-radius": "12px",
        "margin-right": "10px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "=@currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$personIterator.email]",
            "title": "[$personIterator.title]"
          },
          "style": {
            "width": "28px",
            "height": "28px",
            "border-radius": "50%"
          }
        }
      ],
      "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

You can also use the internal name of your person column in place of `@currentField` like `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)